# timetoliveseconds ehcache spring boot config is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

Below is my ehcache Config file

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect"
    dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />



    <cache name="trans"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
        eternal="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="6"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>    
</ehcache>
```

All Spring annotation and configurations are working correctly

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"trans" })
public class MyTransService {

    private List<Trans> list;

    @Autowired
    private EhCacheCacheManager manage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @CachePut
    public void addTransaction(Trans trans) {
        this.list.add(trans);
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    public void deleteAll() {
        this.list.clear();
    }    
}
```

But the cache is not getting clear after **timetoliveseconds**.

Can someone help me whats wrong in my config.

Below page says that it's bug , but not sure how to fix this ?
**I am using spring-boot-starter-cache-2.0.3 version**

https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache/issues/26

there are some similar questions but not providing any solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to resolve this using ehcache-JSR-107 wrapper. Below is java config

```
@Component
public class CachingSetup implements JCacheManagerCustomizer {

     @Override
     public void customize(CacheManager cacheManager)
     {
       cacheManager.createCache("trans", new MutableConfiguration<>()
         .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(SECONDS, 10)))
         .setStoreByValue(false)
         .setStatisticsEnabled(true));
     }
}
```

Pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId> <!--Starter for using Spring Framework's caching support-->
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.cache</groupId> <!-- JSR-107 API-->
          <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are expecting the cache content to disappear without interaction, that is indeed not happening. Ehcache does not have a background check for expired items that removes them eagerly.

Instead removal of expired items happens inline, whenever you try to access them or if during a write to the cache, eviction kicks in because the cache is full.

Comment: Thanks will check that. Was able to resolve using CreatedExpiryPolicy policy